# Delphi 11 Android 64-bit debugger doesn't work Android 9 Samsung or 12 Pixel! Works in "Run without Debugging" mode or in Android 32-bit debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, delphi

Update 8/13/2022

- Setting the target platform to Android 32-bit instead of Android 64-bit works.  Setting the Debugger for Android 64-bit is where it just hangs and hangs.  In Android 64-bit mode, the debugger does respond to when the application exits, but it does not otherwise debug anything in Android 64-bit target platform.
- I was successful at getting Google Pixel 6 to run the debugger in Android 32-bit mode, but it will not work in Android 64-bit mode.

---

edited Aug 2 at 5:57

I have a Pixel 6 Android 12 and a Samsung S8 using Android 9.  Delphi 11 Debugger freezes when it loads the application on them with similar error code!

I searched for similar problem via StackOverflow and google.  I can not seem to find anyone having this issue.  I own a Pixel 6 running Android 12 with Security update July 5,2022.

I can run the program just fine without debugger, but if you run using the play button in Delphi 11, the app just freezes even when Delphi 11 appears that it has loaded a debugger?

If you cancel the app on both phones, it will make Delphi stop and go back to edit mode.  If you press the stop button on Delphi, it will stop the application on both phones.  The main issue I'm having is the the application otherwise is totally frozen when you run Delphi in debugger mode!  Let me tell you again, the application runs fine without debugging.

I followed the steps to "Updating Your Android Tools": found here: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/developing-for-android-11-12-with-delphi-11-alexandria/ and this did not help.

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.2-8557947

I checked to make sure that "Generate Android App Bundle file (arm + arm64)" was set to false.

I'm completely stumped.

**UPDATE NOTE: Delphi 10.4.2 can run and compile for Android 9.0 , BUT it will FREEZE on Android 12.**

```
Platform: remote-android  Connected: no  Process FSP.apk (16554)
Platform: remote-android     Triple: aarch64-*-linux OS Version: 32.0.0 (5.10.81-android12-9-00001-geba40aecb3b7-ab8534902)     Kernel: #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 3 02:46:17 UTC 2022   Hostname: localhost  Connected: yes WorkingDir: /data/user/0/com.embarcadero.FSP  Process FSP.apk (16554)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you find answer ?